# Need Clarity on the Implementation Part of the Diamond Problem

Tags: c#, oop, interface, diamond-problem

Answers for Why multiple inheritances are not possible?

If there is a method in A that B and C have overridden, and D does not override it, then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of C?

Okay. Fine

Why it does not apply to Interfaces?
Because it is not implemented.

This answer is confusing to me. I have seen many articles talking about why multiple inheritances with class are not possible and they never talk about the implementation. When we ask the same question about Interfaces, they don't go with the same logic and now they are saying the code is not implemented. Why don't we go with the same logic? Its implementation is the real problem here? Please address only this part.

Answer (score 1):

Interface is a contract that specify what method the class need to implement, so when you call this method there is only one implementation, unlike multiple inheritance where the compiler wouldn't know what method to take.

In multiple inheritance

```
class A
{
    public void DoSomething() {}
}

class B
{
    public void DoSomething() {}
}

class C : A, B
{
    public override void DoSomething() {} // which DoSomething() is it?
}
```

In multiple interfaces

```
interface A
{
    void DoSomething();
}

interface B
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class C : A, B {
    public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

`DoSomething()` is implemented in class `C`, so the contract with both interfaces is fulfilled.

Comment: See, if we are going to implement the method in Class C, we don't need this inheritance in the first place.

Comment: If we are not using the methods implemented in the base class how we can call this as the inheritance.

Comment: We should then say Multiple inheritances are not possible with Interfaces too. Why don't we say that?

Comment: The code with the multiple inheritance is to show why it isn't possible. When you inherit from another class you don't implement it's methods, you override them, but only if you want to do it. Methods in base class are available in the derived classes (assuming the inheritance is legal).

Comment: The code shows how multiple inheritance is not possible. Fine. Please show me how it is possible using Inheritance. Well, that is what I am reading everywhere. And I know it should be overridden Please read carefully, I said implemented in base class.

Comment: @AjithKumar Multiple inheritance is not possible, it doesn't matter where the implementation is, but I edited the answer withe overriding. The second code block is with implementation of the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The diamond problem arises if B and C, which each supply conflicting definitions for an inherited method, are overridden by D.  The problem would not arise if B and C inherited methods without overriding them, and D supplied overrides for the method, since D's override would affect B and C identically.

If A, B, and C are interfaces, then neither B nor C will be able to supply definitions for the methods of A.  A class which implements both interfaces may do so, but any definition it supplies for the methods of A will apply equally to those of B and C.

Another important difference between interfaces and classes is that when overriding a class member, it's possible to chain to a parent method, but when implementing an interface there's never a parent method to chain to.